# c# savefileDialog IOException "File in use"

Tags: c#

I've looked at other posts on here about this message, but none of them seem to match but scenario, hence the post.

I've trying to save a file (which works fine) but if the file is open but he user, then the exception is thrown (of course).

My question is : How do I save the file to a numerically prefixed name if the selected save as fix is already open?

Or

CATCH the exception to display a "don't be silly, close the file first, then save" message ?

The code I am (currently) using is

```
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        string filter = "CSV file (*.csv)|*.csv| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = filter;

        const string header = "CSV HEADER TITLES";
        string LineOneData = Variables;

        StreamWriter writer = null;

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filter = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            using (writer = new StreamWriter(filter))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(header);
                writer.WriteLine(LineOneData);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: `...  catch(Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }` ?

Comment: Hi @bitbonk, I did try an Exception Catch, but it seems to miss it everytime. I could be wrong, but I thought catching this type of exception was a "no no". Shouldn't I try to evaluate the filename being chosen before the exception is thrown ?

Comment: Can you not set the name using saveFileDialog1.FileName = "THIS.CSV" ?

Comment: Hi @Yahtzee , I'm letting the user pick the filename, so it could be different each time. in the case that they double click on a already existing file (that is currently open) , then I want to stop the save, and either save to the same filename +1 (ie test1.csv) or display a message (instead of crashing the program)

Comment: Depends on what your program is doing but for a certain scenario in which you're editing the file and then saving it within your program the File open code can say that you're looking to read/write.

Comment: Please, consider to take a look at this. It helped me on a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give result in the behavior you wanted: just try to catch `IOException`, due to the file is in use case would throw this. Don't forget to close the writer in the finally block. Also you can throw more exceptions like I showed in case of FileName is null (eventhough this might never happen (?) it shall only show you how you can handle different cases):

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
     try{
        var result = saveFileDialog1.FileName ?? throw new System.IO.IOException("No FileName selected?!");
        writer = new StreamWriter(result);            
        writer.WriteLine(header);
        writer.WriteLine(LineOneData);
        writer.Close();
        }
      catch (System.IO.IOException exp)
        {
          DoSomethingWithThe(exp);
        } 
       finally
        {
          if (writer != null)
            {
                writer.Close();
            }           
        }
    }
```